# Power use question for a trail camera

Tags: power, batteries, portable

I am trying to calculate how long that a trail camera can be deployed before the batteries run out. The trail camera in question is a Reconyx HyperFire 2.

[Here](https://www.trailcampro.com/collections/reconyx-game-camera-reviews/products/reconyx-hyperfire-2) is a useful review of the trail camera that gives a unit of power consumption in Watt seconds.

The trail camera contains 12 AA batteries of either a NiMH or Lithium configuration. We're more interested in the Lithium configuration since the batteries hold up significantly better in cold temperatures.

Here are the quoted power usage figures from the review which I am hoping are correct:

```
Standby Power: 0.65 milliWatts
Picture Day Usage: 1.2 Watt-seconds
Picture Night Usage: 6.5 Watt-seconds

35 * 1.2Ws = 42 Watt seconds for 35 Daytime Photos per day
35 * 6.5Ws = 227.5 Watt seconds for 35 Nighttime Photos per night
0.65mW standby * 24 hours = 15.6 milliWatt-hours per day or 0.0156 Watt-hours per day
```

Technically, it should be 23.98 hours but the difference is not significant enough to consider.

```
Moving on, 3600 Watt seconds make up a Watt Hour
Watt hours are the result of Voltage * Amp Hours
Therefore, Watt Hour / Voltage = Amp Hours

We're interested in finding amps used.

227.5 + 42 = 270 Watt Seconds total for day/night
270 Watt Seconds / 3600 = 0.075 Watt Hours
0.075 Watt-hours + 0.0156 Watt-hours = 0.0906 Watt-hours used total
```

There are two scenarios based on how the trail camera is setup internally.
In the event that the trail cameras operate on 12 Volts DC (12 AA batteries in series):
    0.0906 / 12 = 0.00755 Ampere-hours

Or in the event that they run on 6 Volts DC (two sets of six AA batteries in wired in parallel):

```
0.0906 / 6 = 0.0151 Ampere-hours
```

If the power usage during day and night photography is the same as its given in Watt seconds, then both of these numbers will be equivalent regardless of battery storage capacity.

12 Volt Scenario:

```
3,000mAh or 3Ah
3 / 0.00755 = 397 days (35 day, 35 night shots per day)
```

6 Volt Scenario:

```
6,000mAh or 6Ah
6 / 0.0151 = 397 days (35 day, 35 night shots per day)
```

Okay, that makes sense. The quoted figure for the trail camera run time for day/night photography is 16.6 months.

This is where the review loses me.

```
397 days / 30 = 13.23 months
```

However, if we don't factor in standby power usage, it's 480 days.

```
480 / 30 = 16 months.
0.075 (35 day/night photo power usage only in Watt Hours) / 12 Volts = 0.00625 Amperes

3,000mAh or 3Ah
3 / 0.00625 = 480 days. 480 / 30 = 16 months
```

Please correct me if I have any of this wrong. Obviously there are many variables that effect battery performance, including the electronic components. All I am looking for is a rough estimate based on the available data for deployment in colder temperatures.

I found an article that shows a temperature vs discharge curve for the Energizer Ultimate Lithium battery [here.](https://toolguyd.com/flashlight-tool-batteries-cold-weather/)

If that is to be believed, then the trail camera uses 6.25mA to as much as 12.5mA which means that the effects of colder temperatures on the Energizer Ultimate Lithium batteries should be negligible. The trail camera is drawing less than 25mA which based on the battery discharge curve means that the battery capacity should remain the same.

```
0.00625 Amperes = 6.25mA
0.0125 Amperes = 12.5mA
```

Please double check my calculation or shout WRONG WRONG WRONG while banging a pot or pan with a wooden ladle. Either works.

Comment: The current should change depending on if you use 6V or 12V, without knowing what the power/current draw for each of these voltages are, there isn't a good way to know which one is better. The drop out voltage is also unknown, which is important to know for calculating lifetimes based on discharge curves. If your really that worried about it, then double the amount of batteries.

Comment: 12V = 8 AA batteries in series, 6V = 2 x 4 AA batteries in series.

Comment: I'm only assuming that the device is using a DC-DC converter for the batteries from 1.5 Volts * 12 = 18 Volts or 1.5 Volts * 6 = 9 Volts. The capacity for the Energizer Ultimate Lithium batteries is 3,000mAh per cell.

Comment: I cleaned up some of your unit analysis. Basically, your numbers look right to me. But if you're really using batteries of 18V or 9V, then the current consumption will be 2/3 of what you show and the run time will be 50% longer.

Comment: Okay cool. Thanks!